# Change all rows in a dataframe, following the occurrence of an item in a row.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
Open Close Split
144 144 False
142 143 False
... ... ...
138 139 False
72 73 True
72 74 False
75 76 False
... ... ...
79 78 False
```

Obviously the dataframe can be quite large, and may contain other columns, but this is the core.

My end goal is to adjust all of the data to account for the split, and so far I've been able to identify the split (that's the "Split" column).

Now, I'm looking for an elegant way to divide everything before the split by 2, or multiply everything after the split by 2.

I thought the best way might be to spread the True down towards the bottom, and then multiply all rows that contain a True in the "Split" column, but is there a more Pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Split` is the only boolean column, and that everything else is numeric in nature, you can just take the cumsum and set values with `loc` accordingly -

```
m = df.pop('Split').cumsum()

df.loc[m.eq(0)] /= 2    # division before split 
df.loc[m.eq(1)] *= 2    # multiplication after split
```

```
df    
    Open  Close
0   72.0   72.0
1   71.0   71.5
2   69.0   69.5
3  144.0  146.0
4  144.0  148.0
5  150.0  152.0
6  158.0  156.0
```

This is by far the most performant option. Another possible option involves `np.where` -

```
df[:] = np.where(m.eq(0)[:, None], df / 2, df * 2)
```

```
df
    Open  Close
0   72.0   72.0
1   71.0   71.5
2   69.0   69.5
3  144.0  146.0
4  144.0  148.0
5  150.0  152.0
6  158.0  156.0
```

Or,

`df.where`/`df.mask`  -

```
(df / 2).where(m.eq(0), df * 2)
```

Or,

```
(df / 2).where(m.ne(0), df * 2)
```

```
    Open  Close Split
0   72.0   72.0     0
1   71.0   71.5     0
2   69.0   69.5     0
3  144.0  146.0     2
4  144.0  148.0     0
5  150.0  152.0     0
6  158.0  156.0     0
```

These are nowhere as near efficient as the indexing option with `loc`, because it involves a lot of redundant computation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! I'm actually looking to do just one of the two operations (probably just divide previous values), but I'll adjust that.

Comment: @MattTakao Yes, all 3 options provided are extremely easy to adjust for just one operation. For example. `df.where(m.ne(0), df * 2)` instead of `df / 2` and so on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another `cumsum`-based solution:

```
columns = ['Open','Close']
df[columns] = df[columns].mul(df.Split.cumsum() + 1, axis=0)
#   Open  Close  Split
#0   144    144  False
#1   142    143  False
#2   138    139  False
#3   144    146   True
#4   144    148  False
#5   150    152  False
#6   158    156  False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
split_true = df[df['Split'] == True].index[0]
df.iloc[split_true:,:]
```